# How to change background color of UITableViewCell using my own color combination

Tags: iphone, uitableview, background-color

actually i have found some thread that asking question like mine.
but every solution that given in those thread can not be use in my code..
the last link i was read is 
[How to customize the background color of a UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281515/how-to-customize-the-background-color-of-a-uitableviewcell)

my problem is i just want to change my tableviewcell background color with my own color.
can somebody help me??

Comment: Show the code that you tried in willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: (the whole method including the method name and parameters).  Are you using UITableViewCell or a custom subclass?

Comment: -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView wilLDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 UIView* backgroundView = [ [ [ UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectZero ] autorelease ];
 backgroundView.backgroundColor = [ UIColor yellowColor ];
 cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
 for ( UIView* view in cell.contentView.subviews ) 
 {
  view.backgroundColor = [ UIColor clearColor ];
 }

 
 //cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
 

}

Comment: there is a spelling mistake in your code is should be *willDisplayCell* but in the code you posted it is *wilLDisplayCell* 
please check that ...

Comment: thx gyani....i dont realized it..thank you... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finnaly i found out how to solve this problem. but i was choose to use an image. I was declare my way to solve it in my another question in : [is there somebody who made an application using background for tableview and tableviewcell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425576/is-there-somebody-who-made-an-application-using-background-for-tableview-and-tabl)

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

`[myCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 blue:0.5 green:0.2 alpha:1]];`

One place you could put this would be your table view's `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` data source method. Or else you could subclass UITableViewCell and set it in your overridden initializer. Or you could load the cell from a XIB and use Interface Builder to set the color.

Comment: This has to be done in willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:.  It will not work in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  See the docs for UITableViewCell.

Comment: i was try like that, sorry not declare it in my question, but there's still not displayed the background color

Comment: it's not displayed too, even i moved it into willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
cell.backGroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:190.0/255.0 blue:190.0/255.0 green:190.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Write this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath function.
U will get these kind of different RGB combinations simply from MS Paint and alpha is the opacity ranging in between `0.0` to `1.0`.

Answer (score 1):

another link that help this problem... [UITableViewCell color issues with custom table view background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568508/uitableviewcell-color-issues-with-custom-table-view-background)

Answer (score 1):

**Before iOS 7** Simply add this method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

       [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(221.0/255.0) green:(221.0/255.0) blue:(221.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]];

}
```

Now in **iOS 7** if you put this code in **cellForRowAtIndexPath  it will work**

```
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(221.0/255.0) green:(221.0/255.0) blue:(221.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
```